# How to implement parametrized plot using Jupyter and ipywidgets to work within Vusual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to implement parametrized plotting using Jupyter notebook and ipywidgets to work in VS Code. Below is a snippet I am trying with:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@widgets.interact(freq=(1.0, 10.0))
def plot(freq=1.0):
    t = np.linspace(-1., +1., 1000)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 6))
    ax.plot(t, np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t), lw=2, color='blue')
```

This worked perfectly with Jupyter notebook in a browser, but in VS Code no plot appears. Simple ipywidgets controls like

```
@widgets.interact
def f(x=5):
    print(x)
```

work perfectly good in my VS Code. Is this a general disadvantage of the VS Code Jupyter extension or am I doing things wrongly?

OS: Windows 10, 64 bit;
VS Code Jupyter extension: Miscosoft v. 57,661,722;
IPython: v. 8.9.0;
ipywidgets: v.8.0.4.